# jquery mobile - data-role="listview" seems to be ignored

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

Im using Backbon js, jQuery Mobile and Phonegap/Cordova to develop a simple app, abut im having problems to simply add a list with jQuery Mobile styles/css.

I added a jquery mobile "header" and i can see it on my device. Now i want to add a simple list but instead of pretty list with css, i have a normal html list.

Files used:

- jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css
- jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js

Menu.html

```
<ul id="list_menu" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

    <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>

    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="ISO-8859-1"> 

<title>Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css"/> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/libs/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/json/json2.js"></script> 
<script src="js/libs/jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>  


<!-- other scripts to import like views -->

</head>
<body>

     <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Demo</h1>
        </div>


        <div data-role="content" id="content_application">
            <!-- app running here -->
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have a folder *www/js/libs/jquery_mobile* where i have the css, js and images from jquery mobile.

Im using my Android phone to test, so i dont really know how to debug it.

Comment: can you post how you link to jquery-mobile.js and css files in the header

Comment: If you are adding the listview dynamically, then in script call $("#list_menu").listview(); to initialize the widget.

Comment: @Tasos i edited my post with my index.html.

Comment: @ezanker im NOT adding the list dynamically. I'm adding the list on my html page, so the content doesnt change, its a simple list.

Comment: inside `menu.html` do you have all the necessary `<script>` include? Your list code works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/6HOffRB.jpg

Comment: @Sga i have my index.html with the div _content_application_ where the content from _menu.html_ is being "inflated", so i guess the index.html is always present on every view i load inside this div. Am i wrong?

Comment: you are not "wrong", but that's seems like *adding the list dynamically* to me :-) (that depends on the "inflation" process, is it client side or server side?)

Comment: ok, so in this case is dynamically, but i dont have any code on my javascript side, related with lists. The "inflation" is client side. Inflation code: 'if (!directory.menuView) {
   directory.menuView = new directory.MenuView();
  }
  directory.menuView.$el = $('#content_application');
  directory.menuView.render();'

Comment: you are adding elements to the DOM which have to be enhanced by jQuery Mobile, so you have to call the relative creation method for each one of them (`listview()` in this case)

Comment: @Sga i got it! i did: '$("#list_menu").listview();' on render method and it worked well. Conclusion: what i am doing is dynamically building a component, so i have to create it on javascript side. I think now i got how does it work. :)